# Competitors price tracking tool to automate price tracking for 100000 products?

Tags: python, automation, scraping

I need to build a competitors prices tracking tool for 100,000 products from around 15 competitors? What would be the best way to do it? Please recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [web scraping](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/) chapter of the excellent (and free) eBook "Automate the boring stuff with Python".

That will tell you everything that you need to know.

Comment: This is insightful. But my problem is I don't have competitors URLs for each product. I just have product IDs that are consistent with competitors. The solution should search each individual product ID on the competitors' website, extract prices and keep track of prices. (For Example, I have QWER-1234 as a product id. The solution should search on Amazon, Alibaba,ebay etc. for QWER-1234 and should give me current prices).

Comment: That's not going to happen without some human intervention

Comment: About the only good news is that it you have to do it manually once for each site then you can automate it aft er that. Since it's only 15 sites, that's not too bad, as I would expect them top have the same layout on every page.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit

Comment: Well, for any one of those 15, look at the HTML of any given item; I am sure that you will find a CSS class name and that eh dame class name will work on all pages.  Think about it - if a site sells thousands of items, then it does not have thousands of hand crafted pages - it uses a temple, so that the item name & price, once found on one page, cab be found on the same place on every page. I will happily code it for cash :-)

Comment: done I have coded it.

Comment: Great news! If the answer helped you, please click the tick to accept it, as that will help others who read this question in future (you can upvte it too ;-)  A great book, huh? Make sure to read it all

Comment: Please edit your question and insert the additional details in it.